# How do I display custom field "allow multiple-instances of this field" in types?

Tags: php, wordpress, types, custom-fields

I create types custom field for Playlist URL. I will have Spotify, Youtube or Soundcloud URL. Some playlist will have a spotify url and a youtube url OR Sometimes some playlist will have a soundcloud URL or youtube url. When I add a new url, it works but how do I display it. For example, I want it to display like this.

my code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fboyf8qo/7/)

I want it to display when I click the "listen now" button, so spotify or youtube or soundcloud will appear (the url i put in my custom field).

This is my dynamic code. How do I display custom field "allow multiple-instances of this field" in my "listen now" button? 
See my screenshot, so you know what I’m talking about.
[image: allow mutiple instances of this field]

[image: custom field]

[image: it should show like this dynamic]

I know I have to change the “option-bar” code to display the multiple instance.

```
<div class="option-bar">
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('spotify-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Spotify</a> or <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('youtube-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Youtube</a>
</div>
```

---

```
  <?php

    $args  = array('post_type' => 'music-playlist');
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    $cntr = 0;

    while( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post(); $cntr++; ?>

<section class="row-wrap">
    <div class="row-inner music-wrapper">

        <?php if ($cntr % 2 == 1) { ?>

        <div class="poster-wrap">
            <img class="poster" src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>"> 
        </div>

        <div class="poster-content">
            <h1><?php echo(types_render_field('playlist-name', array('raw' => true) )); ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo(types_render_field('description', array('raw' => true) )); ?></p>

            <button class="btn-wrap">
                <div class="btn">listen now</div>
            </button>

            <div class="option-bar">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('spotify-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Spotify</a> or <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('youtube-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Youtube</a>
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="poster-content">
            <h1><?php echo(types_render_field('playlist-name', array('raw' => true) )); ?></h1>
            <p><?php echo(types_render_field('description', array('raw' => true) )); ?></p>

            <button class="btn-wrap">
                <div class="btn">listen now</div>
            </button>

            <div class="option-bar">
                <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('spotify-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Spotify</a> or <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo(types_render_field('youtube-url', array('raw' => true) )); ?>">Youtube</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="poster-wrap">
            <img class="poster" src="<?php echo(types_render_field('artwork', array('raw' => true) )); ?>"> 
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$paid_mp4_array = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-paid-mp4');
if($paid_mp4_array){
  foreach($paid_mp4_array as $k => $v){
    echo sprintf('<div id="video-%1$s"><source src="%2$s" type="video/mp4" /></div>', $k, $v);
  }
}
```